# How can I fullscreen my canvas & make it fill the screen?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas

I have a HTML5 canvas that when it goes into fullscreen, it does not fill the entire screen.

If I change only the canvas.style.width/height then it works but the display looks bad and also the mouse coordinates are misplaced.

js

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;

canvas.style.left = 0;
canvas.style.top = 0;

onmousemove = function(event) {
    mouseX = (event.pageX - parseFloat(canvas.style.left, 10)) + document.body.scrollLeft;
    mouseY = (event.pageY - parseFloat(canvas.style.top, 10)) + document.body.scrollTop;
}

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
    switch (event.keyCode) {
        case 70:
            if (canvas.requestFullScreen) {
                canvas.requestFullScreen();
            }
            else if (canvas.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
                canvas.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
            } 
            else if (canvas.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                canvas.mozRequestFullScreen();
            }
        break;
    }
});

function on_fullscreen_change() {
    if(document.mozFullScreen || document.webkitIsFullScreen) {
        canvas.style.position = "absolute";
        canvas.style.left = 0;
        canvas.style.top = 0;
        canvas.style.width = screen.width+"px";
        canvas.style.height = screen.height+"px";
        canvas.width = parseFloat(canvas.style.width, 10);
        canvas.height = parseFloat(canvas.style.height, 10);
    }
    else {
        canvas.style.left = 0;
        canvas.style.top = 0;
        canvas.style.width = "1280px";
        canvas.style.height = "720px";
        canvas.width = parseFloat(canvas.style.width, 10);
        canvas.height = parseFloat(canvas.style.height, 10);
    }
}

document.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', on_fullscreen_change);
document.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', on_fullscreen_change);

window.setInterval(function(){

    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.fillStyle = '#0e6eae';
    context.fillRect(mouseX, mouseY, 150, 100);

}, 10);

function getMouseX(){
    return mouseX;
}

function getMouseY(){
    return mouseY;
}
```

css

```
:-webkit-full-screen { width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #000; }
```

EDIT: You can download test files at http://liveweave.com/g5WLW5

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
canvas.width = screen.width;
canvas.height = screen.height;
```

canvas.width and canvas.style.width are two different things. The first resizes the context of the canvas, while the second scales the representation of it.

Comment: If I do that though, the display ends up wrong. (You can download the test files here and check it by pressing the F key http://liveweave.com/g5WLW5 ) I need the canvas to occupy the entire screen however the canvas rendering area should be 720p (1280x720).

Comment: Using var rect = c.getBoundingClientRect(); canvas.width = rect.width; canvas.height = rect.height; seems to keep the 1280 x 768 canvas size but the graphics are a bit blurry and the mouse coordinates are wrong.